# PHP select all data with all their subdata (nested query)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search for all units that belong to an OrderID, and search for all sub_units that belong to the researched units.

So I need to filter this way:

All the data from table "units", where IDorder = $IDOrder
AND search for all data from table "units", where IDMainUnit belongs to the searched units from the first select.

Everything works good with 2 select queries, but now I want to use only one select query.

I tried this way:

```
"SELECT * from units r1 LEFT JOIN units r2 ON r2.IDMainUnit = r1.IDUnit WHERE r1.IDOrder = :IDOrder"
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
I'm studying the behaviour of the JOIN, but I still have to make more experience.

Can you please give me an advise on how to proceed?

If the IDOrder is for example 4, I should then receive the following rows:

```
+---------+--------+------------+-------------+-------+
| IDOrder | IDUnit | IDMainUnit | Description | Price |
+---------+--------+------------+-------------+-------+
|       4 |      5 |            | Product1    | 55.15 |
|         |      6 |          5 | SubProduct1 | 12.15 |
|         |      7 |          5 | SubProduct2 | 13.45 |
|       4 |      8 |            | Product2    | 12.30 |
|       4 |      9 |            | Product3    | 10.15 |
|         |     10 |          9 | SubProduct3 | 08.50 |
+---------+--------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

---

Edit: I've edited the table with a better format. I only have 1 table, but the problem is that for the sub_product, I don't have reference to the IDOrder, but only to the IDMainUnit.

I can write 2 SELECT, like:

```
     SELECT * FROM Units WHERE IDOrder = :IDOrder

    while (PDO:fetch){
    $IDUnit = $PDO['IDUnit'];
    SELECT * FROM Units WHERE IDMainUnit= $IDUnit 
    while(PDO2:fetch){
    }
    }
```

But I don't like this, because if I render everything in a table, then I have to replicate the code 2 times and it become more difficult to maintain.
This is why I'm trying to replicate the 2 queries in only 1 query

Comment: can you share your table?

Comment: Please provide samples data as well.

Comment: `Everything works good with 2 select queries` ... but you only showed us one of the queries.

Comment: Do you have data in column  "IDMainUnit" ? It seems missing common connection between "IDUnit" and "IDMainUnit"

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to combine both query

"SELECT * from units r1 JOIN units r2 ON r2.IDMainUnit = r1.IDUnit WHERE r1.IDOrder = :IDOrder"

Here You have to use only "JOIN" instead of "LEFT JOIN"

Comment: unfortunately is not working, it only takes:
Product1
Product2
Product3 
(and not the subproducts)